# Как нужно указывать адрес файла, чтобы запущены мной код, по нажатию кнопки печатал его содержимое? Файл должен быть локальным

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
   function getFile() {
      $.get("ajax_1.txt", function(data) {
        $("#text").append(data);
      });
    }
  </script>

<div id = "text">  
  <button onclick = "getFile()" id = "button">Get Information</button>  
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "локальным" - на клиенте?

Comment: @Igor Да, на клиенте.

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж используете `jQuery`, воспользуйтесь функцией `load`

```
 function getFile() {
     $( "#text" ).load( "ajax_1.txt" );
 }
```

Не забывайте про то что путь у вас относительный и файл ищется в том месте, где лежит исполняющий скрипт. Т.е. чтоб наверняка, лучше пользуйтесь  `"/your/path/on/server/ajax_1.txt"`  ну или как вам удобнее.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Oба файла лежат в одной папке. А почему лyчше воспользоваться __load__?

Comment: Нипочему. Он делает другое.

Comment: @Igor почему программа не находит файл, лежащий в той же папке, что и код.

Comment: Кстати говоря я сам не делал так. Будет ли он загружать txt файлы ? По идее должен.

Comment: @Михаил Вы же сказали, что файл находится на клиенте.

Comment: @Igor перепутал